# VBA keeps changing periods to commas

Tags: excel, vba, locale, regional-settings

I made a vba script that should change a specific area's values from comma-separated to dot-separated.

Here is the code:

```
Sub commas_to_periods()
'
' commas_to_periods Macro
' Convert all commas to Periods in a specified area that contains values before converting the file to csv
'

'
    Range("U3:AJ139").Select
    ' Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    ' Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    '    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    '    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
    Dim V As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, T
    V = Range("U3:AJ139").Value
    howMany = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    T = Timer
    For i = LBound(V, 1) To UBound(V, 1)
        For j = LBound(V, 2) To UBound(V, 2)
            If InStr(V(i, j), ",") > 0 Then
                V(i, j) = Replace(V(i, j), ",", ".")
                howMany = howMany + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("U3:AJ139").Value = V
    msgForBox = "That took " & Timer - T & " Seconds and found: " & howMany & " commas"
    MsgBox (msgForBox)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

I tried a couple of ways as you see but I also used that custom loop to have it count the replacements. I just can't get it to work! The message box displays that it found 100+ commas, but when the macro is done no change is made. The next time I run it, I get the exact same message in the box. Same number of commas found - no change!

If I try to replace anything else, it works just fine. Replacements are made. When I try it with the comma, it stubbornly doesn't work. Now I suppose it has something to do with my regional settings but I can't figure out a workaround. When I do a manual search and replace the commas get changed. I even recorded a macro of me making a manual search and replace and I got the same result. It seems that VBA reverts my changes to comply with my regional settings. Is there a way to go around that?

Comment: Are there strings stored in these cells? If not, maybe change only the NumberFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if your regional settings are set to `,` as decimal points that means any numeber that contains a `.` will be treated as Text.

So if you want that Excel does not convert them into a number you need to ensure the number format of your cell is set to text: `.NumberFormat = "@"` before writing the number containing a `.` dot.

For example

```
Sub a()
    
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Selection = Replace(Selection, ",", ".")

End Sub
```

For multiple cells you will need to loop:

```
Sub b()   
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Selection
    
    Rng.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    Dim Cell As Variant
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        Cell.Value2 = Replace$(Cell.Value2, ",", ".")
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

because any other solution does not work as Excel thinks it is smart and turns any text back into a number.

[image]

Comment: That's a good point. The cells actually are set to text at the creation of the sheet. They are text. For some reason, excel insists on converting all to commas. I'm baffled.
I tried it on 2 Computers running windows and one Mac. The result is the same.

Comment: @escozul I can't agree. If I turn the cell into text `.NumberFormat = "@"` **before** replacing it does the replacing correctly. See my edited example.

Comment: @Peh ah, that was the only thing that worked till now. It works however only on single-cell selection. if I try to change it to a cell area I get a type mismatch error. Using the other replacement methods like `Selection.Replace What` etc I still  get the same result.

Comment: You need to loop and replace every single cell. Turning off screen updating will make it faster, working with arrays doesn't work neiter.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Interesting how `Selection.Replace What:=` doesn't work when `Replace$()` does. Is the $ that makes the difference?

Comment: @escozul 2 entirely different methods. The problem is that Excel replaces `,` with `.` then sees *"oh the decimal separator is `,` but the value entered in the cell is with `.` the user probably meant this to be a number, I'll convert that because I'm so smart"* and then you end up with messed up data. Thank you Microsoft!

Comment: Yup! figured that's what was going on in milliseconds back there as I was trying to make it work. Your help was invaluable and really educational.